# jQuery Datatables find last row, and get data from first column which is a hidden column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatables driven table setup, which has a couple hidden columns in it. From which I am trying to figure out how to find the last row of that table with a specific class. So I can then take the first column of it which is one of the hidden columns and use its data for a part of another script I am writing. As I understand it `fnGetData()` is the function I am looking to use. But finding the last row (tr) with a specific class (which there are multiple rows with that class). Then using that row as a means to get the data from that first hidden column so I can work with it seems to be evading me.

I need an idea of how to find that last row, and use it the way that is hoped. Any idea's? Also outside of the methods found on the datatables api docs, I haven't tried much outside of that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Made a quick and simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkt3s/2) of how I understood your table to work; and the jQuery I used:

```
$(".row:last td:hidden:first").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. Use the :last selector.

```
$(".trclass:last").children(".hiddenCol") .....
```